# Spaces required between keyword and literal

Tags: javascript, syntax, whitespace

Looking at the output of UglifyJS2, I noticed that no spaces are required between literals and the `in` operator (e.g., `'foo'in{foo:'bar'}` is valid).

Playing around with Chrome's DevTools, however, I noticed that hex and binary number literals require a space before the `in` keyword:

[image]

Internet explorer returned true to all three tests, while FireFox 48.0.1 threw a SyntaxError for the first one (`1in foo`), however it is okay with string literals (`'1'in foo==true`).

It seems that there should be no problem parsing JavaScript, allowing for keywords to be next to numeric literals, but I can't find any explicit rule in the ECMAScript specification (any of them).

Further testing shows that statements like `for(var i of[1,2,3])...` are allowed in both Chrome and FireFox (IE11 doesn't support for..of loops), and `typeof"string"` works in all three.

Which behavior is correct? Is it, in fact, defined somewhere that I missed, or are all these effects a result of idiosyncrasies of each browser's parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert - I haven't done a JS compiler, but have done others.

ecma-262.pdf is a bit vague, but it's clear that an expression such as `1 in foo` should be parsed as 3 input elements, which are all tokens. Each token is a `CommonToken` (11.5); in this case, we get `numericLiteral`, `identifierName` (yes, `in` is an `identifierName`), and `identifierName`. Exactly the same is true when parsing `0b1 in foo` (see 11.8.3).

So, what happens when you take out the WS? It's not covered explicitly (as far as I can see), but it's common practice (in other languages) when writing a lexer to scan the longest character sequence that will match something you could potentially be looking for.  The introduction to section 11 pretty much says exactly that:

> The source text is scanned from left to right, repeatedly taking the
>   longest possible sequence of code points as the next input element.

So, for `0b1in foo` the lexer goes through `0b1`, which matches a numeric literal, and reaches `i`, giving `0b1i`, which doesn't match anything. So it passes the longest match (`0b1`) to the rest of the parser as a token, and starts again at `i`. It finds `n`, followed by WS, so passes `in` as the second token, and so on.

So, basically, and rather bizarrely, it looks like IE is correct.

Comment: See [ECMA 262](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf) § 7.8.3, which says otherwise: `The source character immediately following a NumericLiteral must not be an IdentifierStart or DecimalDigit.`. Unfortunately, this is one of those cases where IE's strategy on anything makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
There would be no change to how code would be interpreted if whitespace weren't required in these circumstances, but it's part of the spec.

Looking at the [source code of v8 that handles number literal parsing](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/parsing/scanner.cc#L1153), it cites [ECMA 262](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf) § 7.8.3:

> The source character immediately following a NumericLiteral must not be an IdentifierStart or DecimalDigit.
>
> **NOTE** For example:
>
> `3in`
>
> is an error and not the two input elements **3** and **in**.

This section seems to contradict the introduction of section 7. However, it does not seem that there would be any problems with breaking that rule and allowing for `3in` to be parsed. There are cases where allowing for no spaces between literals and identifiers would change how the source is parsed, but all cases merely change which errors are generated.

Comment: Well spotted - the relevant section in the current spec is 11.8.3, p168. I should have realised there was a problem when IE appeared to get it right...